# Converting DOCX / Word-generated XML to JSON

Tags: php, json, xml, openxml, docx

I am trying to convert a Word-generated XML file to JSON through PHP.

I have looked around and found for all XML files the best case to be the following code (even on PHP documentation):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

The problem is that after `simplexml_load_string` I get an empty `SimpleXMLElement` object and the rest of the steps cannot really go through.
The xml itself begins as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:wordDocument
```

and the tags have a prefix of `w:`.
I have tried removing the `w:`s but again the function returns an empty object. Any idea what I might be missing? Is there anything special about this type of generated XML ?

Comment: Short answer: Don't. Word is a complex format with mixed nodes. Parsing it into SimpleXML objects and serializing them will not work (you loose to much information) and any JSON structure keeping that information will be as complex as the original XML. Try reading the specific information from the XML that you need using DOM and Xpath (better handling of namespaces and mixed nodes) and build an array/object structure from them. Encode that generated structure.

Comment: I wouldn't say don't. [This python package](https://github.com/microsoft/Simplify-Docx) does just that. You'd have to pass doc from PHP on to a python server (aiohttp / django, etc), but [that isn't impossible](https://www.docx2json.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ThW [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475323/converting-word-generated-xml-to-json#comment99541133_56475323) correct: **Don't convert OOXML to JSON.**  It won't help.

The complexity of OOXML (the standard behind DOCX) will not be tamed by conversion to JSON.  A successful JSON conversion would be challenging and would only really serve to provide appreciation of the general advice to use ***XML for documents and JSON for data***.

See also [JSON or XML? Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045237/json-or-xml-which-is-better) and note:

- OOXML is an existing, highly complex standard for *documents*, not *data*.
- Existing OOXML tool infrastructure is 100% XML-based.
- Representing documents requires representation of mixed-content
  – something JSON is not designed to do.<sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup> Somewhat ironically,
   mixed content is rarely used in OOXML: Runs of text are generally
   wrapped within `w:r/w:t` elements.  If you're looking for inspiration that
   a JSON-based DOCX representation would be *possible*, this is it.
   If you're looking to understand how JSON wouldn't tame the DOCX
   complexity, this should also help.  :-)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

check out this question: [Simplexml_load_string($string) returns an empty object but $string contains xml? code below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165048/simplexml-load-stringstring-returns-an-empty-object-but-string-contains-xml)

It´s pretty similar.

Could you try to print $xml?
Maybe the error isn´t the simplexml_load_string but the json_encode...

BR
Marc